# How can I get the average of the 4 most recent weeks of data in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, average

How can I get the average of the 4 most recent weeks of data in Oracle? The current week is not included, as it's an incomplete week

Assume that for each of the dates (column name: DATEFILED), we have a certain number of vouchers filed. Say we have this data over a period of several weeks, and you want the weekly average of the voucher count over the past 4 complete weeks

This is the query I came up with. I am wondering if anyone has a better solution for this

```
WITH cteFOURWEEKPERIOD AS 
(SELECT NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE - 28, 'SAT') AS BEGINNING_SUNDAY,
NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE - 7, 'SUN') AS ENDING_SATURDAY
FROM DUAL)
SELECT (COUNT(VOUCHERS))/4 AS AVG_COUNT, SYSDATE AS "AS OF"
FROM CLAIMS C
CROSS JOIN cteFOURWEEKPERIOD F
WHERE C.DATEFILED BETWEEN F.BEGINNING_SUNDAY AND F.ENDING_SATURDAY;
```

Comment: Hi.  Please read [ask].  Edit the question and show the table definition with example data, and what you have attempted.  thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "average of weeks"? Weeks are time periods, they are not numbers - what does "average" mean in this context?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This script appears to have worked

```
WITH cteFOURWEEKPERIOD AS 
(SELECT NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE - 28, 'SAT') AS BEGINNING_SUNDAY,
NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE - 7, 'SUN') AS ENDING_SATURDAY
FROM DUAL)
SELECT (COUNT(VOUCHERS))/4 AS AVG_COUNT, SYSDATE AS "AS OF"
FROM CLAIMS C
CROSS JOIN cteFOURWEEKPERIOD F
WHERE C.DATEFILED BETWEEN F.BEGINNING_SUNDAY AND F.ENDING_SATURDAY;
```